# O que significa "ARAÚJO"

Tags: significado, etimologia

Essa palavra tem algum significado alem de ser sobrenome?

Muitos (a maioria?) de sobrenomes tem significados alem de ser nomes:

Santo = sagrado ou santificado

Oliveira = um tipo de arvore

Qual significado tem o nome ARAÚJO ?

Comment: "O sobrenome surgiu na Espanha através do Castelo de Araúja, localizado próximo ao rio Minho. Ele é considerado, por esse motivo, de origem geográfica, ou seja, um toponímico. Araújo é derivado de Araúja, uma árvore." "Rodrigues Anes de Araújo, senhor do Castelo de Araújo, que ficava por lá, foi provavelmente a primeira pessoa a usar o sobrenome, por volta do século 13."

Comment: Fontes: revista [Super Interessante](https://super.abril.com.br/mundo-estranho/a-origem-dos-15-sobrenomes-brasileiros-mais-populares/), [Origem do Sobrenome](https://www.origemdosobrenome.com.br/familia-araujo/), e [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ara%C3%BAjo).

Comment: @stafusa Quer dizer que é (ou era) nome de uma espécie de árvore?  Ou somente o nome de um organismo individual, de espécie indeterminada?

Comment: Antes uma ressalva: coloquei como comentário e não como resposta, por não ter fontes confiáveis (a Wikipedia normalmente seria, mas esse verbete não aponta fontes, então não é). Respondendo à tua pergunta, a origem mais mencionada é a do castelo, que o nome do castelo deriva de uma árvore tenho a impressão de ser mencionado com menor frequência, e, sim, entendo que seria uma espécie específica, não um indivíduo específico.

Comment: Isso da árvore deve ser confusão. Não encontrei nenhuma árvore araúja a não ser nesses sites sobre o sobrenome. O que há é uma planta trepadeira sul-americana, conhecida por *pepino-de-seda* ou *timbo*, que no sXIX recebeu o nome científico [*araujia*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araujia_sericifera) em homenagem a um tal António de Araújo e Azevedo.

Comment: Só lembrando algo importante: isso não são "significados" de sobrenomes, são origens, é a etimologia da palavra, não o significado!